# Creating a Cursor Follow Script Without Breaking Usability

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning how to make a script that creates a circle following the mouse cursor similar to the script below:
https://www.kirupa.com/canvas/follow_mouse_cursor.htm

This script will darken the whole website except for the part inside the circle, which will be visible at normal brightness.

However, using the author's canvas approach the user can not interact with the website underneath, as there is an overlay over the website.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: There's no question here. You're literally asking people to design and implement code for you. This is a site for asking question and debugging tips on code you've at least attempted to make.

Comment: You can disable the cursor events for any HTML element using the CSS pointer-events rule. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML works in layers, there's really no way to have an element under the mouse and properly interact with the elements underneath.

Instead, what you may want to think about, instead of showing only whats under the mouse, hiding everything that isn't under the mouse.

The could be achieved by creating elements that stay a number of pixels away from the cursor, leaving a window into the site.

I made an example of this on JSFiddle, here is the important part using JQuery (although it could easily be done in plan JS as well).

```
var offset = 50; //the area around the cursor that is visible

$("body").mousemove(function(e){
    var newPos = (e.pageX - offset);
    $("#left").width(newPos);
    $("#top,#bottom").css("left", newPos);

    newPos = (window.innerWidth - (e.pageX + (offset + 17)));
    $("#right").width(newPos);

    newPos = (e.pageY - offset);
    $("#top").height(newPos);

    newPos = (window.innerHeight - (e.pageY + offset));
    $("#bottom").height(newPos);
})
```

[JSFiddle with full code.](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/jL79gcLd/) Note that the text can still be selected as usual.